# LXD ZFS storage pool on lvm filesystem?

Tags: lvm, virtual-machine, zfs, lxc, lxd

The default filesystem of my machine is lvm (Ubuntu 22.04). I would like to spin up LXD/LXC virtual machines to run some Apache projects like Hadoop and Spark. When setting up Hadoop there is a step where I need to format the filesystem within the VM to hdfs and I don't know how that would affect the system if my storage is DIR and not a system like zfs. Furthermore, I cannot manually assign a custom size to a DIR storage, but I can on ZFS.

ZFS seems the superior option but the problem is my native filesystem is lvm not zfs. Is it possible to have zfs storage despite lvm filesystem underneath or do I need to change my entire filesystem to zfs?

When I run `lxd init` the setup does offer to me to make my backend storage zfs [default=zfs].

Any insight on ZFS/LVM coexistence is greatly appreciated. I am not very fluent in this topic and I don't want to break my machine :)

Answer (score 1):

LVM is not a filesystem, it is a volume management tool for disks & partitions.  Saying "lvm is my default filesystem" is like saying "fdisk is my default filesystem".

You can use ZFS (or any other filesystem, such as ext2/3/4, xfs, btrfs, etc) on one or more logical volume(s) provided by LVM...however, there's little point in doing so. Unless you need LVM on the host system for other reasons, you're better off just using ZFS, as ZFS provides both disk/partition/volume/pool management AND a filesystem.

e.g. you might want the host OS on xfs or ext4 and a zpool for the VM disk images (the only good reason to do that is that it can be difficult to run zfs on the root filesystem, but even that's not as hard as some people think it is).  There are many ways to do that but, they all boil down to "allocate some of the disk space to partitions/LVs for /, /boot, /boot/EFI, etc, and allocate the remainder to ZFS".

You can use RAID for the non-ZFS partitions if you want, but you should give raw partitions or LVs to ZFS so that it can create and manage the zpool itself.   Using ZFS on top of raid (whether HW raid or SW raid like mdadm or lvm's raid features) is an extremely bad idea....it completely undermines ZFS's best feature, its ability to use block checksums and redundancy copies to not only detect errors but to **repair** them.

For each VM's virtual disk(s) on ZFS,you can either use raw disk image files (qcow2 isn't needed because zfs has built-in transparent compression) or create ZVOLs as needed for each VM (e.g. `zfs create -V 10G pool/myvmname`).

BTW, I use both on my systems - for some VMs I use disk image files, for others I use zvols, and sometimes I use both in a VM (e.g. for my `ztest` VM for testing zfs/lvm/raid/btrfs and other disk & filesystem related stuff, I use a 10GB ZVOL for the OS, and a bunch of 100MB disk image files as virtual disks for testing stuff with - very handy for learning and practising stuff like rolling back a snapshot, restoring backups, and recovering from disasters before you need it in real-life).

A zvol is a chunk of the zpool that presents to the system as just another block device (so can be partitioned and/or formatted and used like any other block device).The main advantage of using a zvol is that each zvol can be independently snapshotted for backup and/or disaster recovery. It's also easy to increase the size of a zvol with, e.g., `zfs set volsize="$newsize" poolname/zvolname` (you'll still need to edit the zvol's partition table and run `xfs_growfs` or `resize2fs` or whatever, either inside the VM while it's running or from the host while the VM is shut down)

You can also use qcow2 files on ZFS, but there's no point as zfs already does compression and snapshotting and a lot more...and doubling up on those features will just make it a bit slower.  If you already have a .qcow2 file containing your VM, IMO your best option is to use `qemu-img convert` to turn it into a raw disk image and save that to either a file or directly to a ZVOL's block device node under /dev/zvol/pool.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can have ZFS running on top of LVM, LVM in top of ZFS or both running side by side on different parts of your storage. But both are doing the same thing in this context - volume management - providing a space where you can provision a HDFS filesystem. ZFS is really good at what it does, but you would get NONE of the benefits but all of the drawbacks of ZFS running it on top of LVM.

Just use a qcow2 virtual disk.

If your existing storage is conigured as lvm-thin, then you can provision this as a new logical volume. If its just lvm2 put it on an existing filesystem.